# Is there anyway that I can look into how they computed deviance residuals in stat package?

Tags: r

I fitted the simple logistic regression model,
But I want to look into the codes they computed residuals,
Specifically,

```
fit <- glm(y~x, data=my, family=binomial(link="logit"))
fit$residuals
```

It is my first time trying to locate the code in the base package, I am guessing for built in packages, there is no source package where you can open up each function contained in the package as other regular packages, I tried just typing

```
 glm

> glm
function (formula, family = gaussian, data, weights, subset, 
    na.action, start = NULL, etastart, mustart, offset, control = list(...), 
    model = TRUE, method = "glm.fit", x = FALSE, y = TRUE, contrasts = NULL, 
    ...) 
{
    call <- match.call()
    if (is.character(family)) 
        family <- get(family, mode = "function", envir = parent.frame())
    if (is.function(family)) 
        family <- family()
<bytecode: 0x0000000014da21b0>
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

and starting from there, but I have no idea how to locate the code that I want,
Could anyone give me the insight? Any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: I think you're after `binomial(link="logit")$dev.resids`. Follow the guide on the duplicate question to find the code for `binomial_dev_resids`.

Comment: thank you, sorry for duplicated question